# How to convert bloc to cubit?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use bloc but I want to remake this code into `cubit` because I don't have to use event, I can remove them. I tried to do this, but I got an error and the code did not work, but I don’t understand what I could be wrong about. I will be grateful if you help me correctly conveyed Tell me, how can I convert bloc into `cubit` correctly (I don’t have to use the event)?

**bloc**

```
class ConnectedBloc extends Bloc<ConnectedEvent, ConnectedState> {
  StreamSubscription? subscription;

  ConnectedBloc() : super(ConnectedInitial()) {
    on<OnConnectedEvent>((event, emit) => emit(ConnectedSucess()));
    on<OnNotConnectedEvent>((event, emit) => emit(ConnectedFailure()));

    var resultCon = Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

    if (resultCon == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
        resultCon == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      add(OnConnectedEvent());
    } else {
      add(OnNotConnectedEvent());
    }

    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
          result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        add(OnConnectedEvent());
      } else {
        add(OnNotConnectedEvent());
      }
    });

    @override
    Future<void> close() {
      subscription?.cancel();
      return super.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**event**

```
abstract class ConnectedEvent {}

class OnConnectedEvent extends ConnectedEvent {}

class OnNotConnectedEvent extends ConnectedEvent {}
```

**state**

```
abstract class ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedInitial extends ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedSucess extends ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedFailure extends ConnectedState {}
```

**home**

```
home: BlocConsumer<ConnectedBloc, ConnectedState>(
          listener: ((context, state) {
            if (state is ConnectedFailure) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your event classes and extend `ConnectivityCubit` class from `Cubit` instead of `Bloc`.

```
abstract class ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedInitial extends ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedSuccess extends ConnectedState {}

class ConnectedFailure extends ConnectedState {}



class ConnectivityCubit extends Cubit<ConnectedState> {
  late final StreamSubscription connectivityStreamSubscription;
  final Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();

  ConnectivityCubit() : super(ConnectedInitial()) {
    connectivityStreamSubscription =
        connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
          result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        emit(ConnectedSuccess());
      } else {
        emit(ConnectedFailure());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    connectivityStreamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me if I can do 2 methods? One close() method that is already there and make another one with the code above?

Comment: Both close methods are doing the same things i.e closing stream subscription.

Comment: You did not understand. I have a function onConnectivityChanged and I want to put it in a separate method so that it is like a separate method like void connection()...

Comment: Please elaborate. can't understand

Comment: See I need this code here connectivityStreamSubscription =
         connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result)... also put in a method so I can call it later

Comment: Separate this code

Comment: Yes, you can. But why do you want to call this again as you are already listening to the connection changes.

Comment: I just need to call the method in the UI when the button is clicked to check the Internet connection